# "Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined" in React component

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am using Reactstrap in my project for Bootstrap integration. However, I also need to extend the `onClick` behavior of the `Button` component that comes out of the box with Reactstrap. To that end, I have made a custom `NanoButton` component that recomposes the default one. This is how I'm calling it:

```
<NanoButton type="button" onClick={() => Router.push('/about')}>About</NanoButton>
```

The `NanoButton` component, as I said, adds my custom `onClick` functionality to the existing `Button` class:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

class NanoButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick(e) {
        var circle = document.createElement('div');
        e.target.appendChild(circle);
        var d = Math.max(e.target.clientWidth, e.target.clientHeight);
        circle.style.width = circle.style.height = d + 'px';
        var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        circle.style.left = e.clientX - rect.left -d/2 + 'px';
        circle.style.top = e.clientY - rect.top - d/2 + 'px';
        circle.classList.add('ripple');

        this.props.onClick();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        className={this.props.className}
        type={this.props.type}
        color={this.props.color}
        size={this.props.size}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default NanoButton;
```

As you can see, I need the `NanoButton` component to perform some custom activities before finally executing the `onClick` function passed to it as the prop. But when loading in browser, it fails at `this.props.onClick();` saying it cannot read `onClick on undefined`? What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `onClick` method is not bound to your class context, and therefore have no access to `this.props`.

The usual solution is to bind this method in your constructor :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
```

Another option is to bind in the render method as it's been suggested, however this means that the binding will be done at each render, instead of only one-time using the constructor solution.

Comment: See my comment to the previous answer.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, and this should work, the problem here come from the line `this.props.onClick();` in onClick method, since this method is not bound to the class, `this.props` is undefined.

Comment: But if I bind it, only the onClick passed as props would execute and the one defined in the component skipped. That's not what I'm looking for. I need to execute the onClick defined in NanoButton **before** executing the onClick passed to it as props.

Comment: Both will be executed, since this.props.onClick is called at the end of NanoButton onClick. Binding just give to NanoButton's onClick the reference of the other onClick so it can be called

Comment: You should try this solution with some `console.log` in both onClick methods to make sure it works as intended

Comment: Tried it and as expected, the in-class onClick gets totally skipped and only the one passed as prop gets executed.

Comment: I don't understand how the in-class `onClick` can be skipped since it's the only place where `this.props.onClick` is called

Comment: I have updated the code in the question with your suggestion.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it passes in the in-class `onClick`, I checked with an `alert`. Moreover, the button grows as it is supposed to. Therefore, everything seems to work. You can test it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/7158l4o12j

Comment: But the code is exactly as I've posted and it still skips the in-class function if bound. I have the entire project up on github if you wish to take a look.

Comment: Can you give me your github url ? Did the code on my link work as expected ?

Comment: Here's my repo: https://github.com/amitsch666/nano. If you're cloning it, just try visiting the /page2 link. That's the page2.js file where I have implemented this component. As for your test, I tried running it. The alert pops up alright, but still fails at the this.props.onClick but with a different error.

Comment: Yeah the error is that Router is not defined, which is normal since it's not imported (as in your code). I'll try to run your project

Comment: Alright, turns out you were right all along and the problem is not in the order of execution but somewhere else. It seems the `props.onClick` method is executing almost instantly whereas the in-class `onClick` sets a CSS animation that needs 600 milliseconds to complete. That's why it gives an illusion that the animation didn't trigger at all. I have accepted your answer and posted another question to illustrate the now-identified issue. Mind taking a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746939/how-to-defer-this-props-onclick-until-after-a-css-animation-is-complete

Answer (score 3):

This occurs when `this` is not defined in the function **context**,So for solving that You just need to bind this action, So for doing that you can bind this either in your constructor method or you can directly bind this with the function whenever it is passed as props in the render function.

**Binding directly in Constructor**

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
```

**Passing as a props:-**

```
<Button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)/>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to forget about when to bind or not your methods you can replace the following style:

```
onClick(e) {

}
```

with:

```
onClick = (e) => {
  this.props.onClick();
}
```

and the arrow function will automatically bind everything for you, you don't need to change your code only the way you define these methods.

the reason of `onClick on undefined` error is because indeed onClick is defined in the scope of the Dom element which lacks the onClick method definition.

Comment: I need to execute both onClick's and binding it doesn't accomplish that. If I just wanted to execute this.props.onClick, I would just pass it on as a prop to <Button>`, but I also need to execute the onClick defined within <NanoButton> before this.props.onClick.

Comment: put a debugger and inspect the `this` variable should be your React class component, honestly, I think you are missing something in your code, this code allowed to execute some code and then fire the callback, I use it all the time.