# How to defer this.props.onClick() until after a CSS animation is complete?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, next.js

I am calling a custom `NanoButton` component from my page along with an `onClick` instruction to route to another page:

```
// Page.js
import { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
class Page2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <NanoButton type="button" color="success" size="lg" onClick={() => Router.push('/about')}>About</NanoButton>
    )
  }
}
```

When the button (`NanoButton` component) is clicked, I want to execute some internal code before moving on to the `onClick` coming in as props. Through this internal code, I am trying to simulate the material-design ripple effect that lasts 600 milliseconds. This is how I do it:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

class NanoButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  onClick(e) {
    this.makeRipple(e);
    this.props.onClick();
  }
  makeRipple(e) {
    const elements = e.target.getElementsByTagName('div');
    while (elements[0]) elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    const circle = document.createElement('div');
    e.target.appendChild(circle);
    const d = Math.max(e.target.clientWidth, e.target.clientHeight);
    circle.style.width = `${d}px`;
    circle.style.height = `${d}px`;
    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    circle.style.left = `${e.clientX - rect.left - (d / 2)}px`;
    circle.style.top = `${e.clientY - rect.top - (d / 2)}px`;
    circle.classList.add('ripple');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        className={this.props.className}
        type={this.props.type}
        color={this.props.color}
        size={this.props.size}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default NanoButton;
```

So as you can see, I need the `makeRipple` method to execute before `this.props.onClick`. And initially, it didn't seem to doing that. However, after further testing, it turns out that the methods do run in the right order after all, except the routing (as coded in `this.props.onClick`) happens instantly and the ripple animation that's styled to last 600 milliseconds doesn't get a chance to run. The CSS that makes this animation happen is:

```
button {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

button .ripple {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: ripple 0.6s linear;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    to {
        transform: scale(2.5);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

How do I make the `this.props.onClick` run only **AFTER** the animation is complete? I tried setting a timeout like so:

`setTimeout(this.props.onClick(), 600);`

But that throws an error.

**Note**: I'm using [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) for server side rendering, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You should "reactify" `makeRipple` by allowing `state` and `render` to do all the work, instead of manipulating the DOM directly, which is discouraged in React.

Comment: Tried that too, but it doesn't allow me to set style attributes (`height`, `width`, `top`, and `left`) dynamically. I am unable to use, say, something like `style=${this.state.rippleStyle}` on my `div` as it throws an invariant violation error. Any feedback?

Comment: I guess one way to hack around it would be to have `makeRipple` return a Promise that applies the animation, then just resolves. `onClick(e) { this.makeRipple(e).then(() => this.props.onClick() ) }`     `makeRipple(e) { return new Promise((resolve) => { ...do animation... resolve() }  )}`

Comment: But that would help only if makeRipple weren't executing before props.onClick. In my case, the order of execution is not a problem, it's just that the onClick doesn't wait for the **CSS** to finish animating. makeRipple is done once it adds the ripple element, it's the animation I need to wait for before firing props.onClick.

Comment: You'll need a timeout to delay the action. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Exactly! But when I tried using setTimeout(), it threw a very unhelpful `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` with no further information. The error occurs on some file named VM14477 (must be some internal NextJS thing; the number changes every time the page reloads) which has only one line of code: `[object Promise]`. There's no way I can do anything about this file because it's being created on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it, like `Promise`, `async/await`, etc.
But if you try `setTimeout` please use

```
setTimeout(() => this.props.onClick(), 600);
```

or

```
setTimeout(this.props.onClick, 600);
```

your case:

```
setTimeout(this.props.onClick(), 600);
```

won't work because this line will pass the result of `this.props.onClick()` into the first param instead of passing the whole function.

Comment: Like I've mentioned in the question, I've already tried setTimeout.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `setTimeout(this.props.onClick(), 600);` won't work. You should put the function into first parameter of `setTimeout`, but not the result of `this.props.onClick()`. That could be the simplest method to handle the delay.

Comment: Wow, you're a lifesaver! `setTimeout(() => this.props.onClick(), 600);` actually did work! Could you please add maybe a couple of lines to your answer explaining why the fat arrow syntax works in this case and not the regular one? Would be a great help to anyone else looking for a similar solution in future. Again, thanks a ton. :)