# Material-ui Button onClick() causes "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, web, material-ui

I have a material ui button that has an OnClick function. But for some reason, when I clicked on the button, it is not working and gives me the error shown above.

May I know what am I doing wrong here? 
I have used constructor as suggested here: [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737145/cannot-read-property-onclick-of-undefined-in-react-component)
but it's still not working

**Props**:

```
type Props = {
  showSmallHero: () => void,
  fetchTalentIfNeeded: () => void,
  submitJobApplicationIfNeeded: () => void,
  talent: Object,
};
```

**My Code**:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.showSmallHero();
    this.props.fetchTalentIfNeeded();
  }

  handleChange = (event, d) => {
    const { target } = event;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    if (d.name === 'gender') {
      this.setState({
        [d.name]: d.value,
      });
    } else if (d.name === 'resume') {
      // This is a file
    } else {
      const { name } = target;
      this.setState({
        [name]: value,
      });
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('resume');
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('full-name', this.state.fullName);
    formData.append('gender', this.state.gender);
    formData.append('nric', this.state.nationalId);
    formData.append('email', this.state.email);
    formData.append('phone-number', this.state.phoneNumber);
    formData.append('position-applied', this.state.jobName);
    formData.append('job-id', this.state.jobId);
    formData.append('experience', this.state.experience);
    formData.append('academic-result', this.state.academicResult);
    formData.append('resume', file);
    this.props.submitJobApplicationIfNeeded(formData);
  };

  handleClick = (e, d) => {
    this.setState({ jobName: d.name, jobId: d.id, showModal: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  };


render() {

<Button
     variant="contained"
     size="medium"
     color="secondary"
     id={t.acf.job_id}
     name={t.acf.job_name}
     onClick={this.handleClick}
     >
     Apply
     </Button>
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, as I can see there are two parameters in the method defination and on click only event object is there!

Comment: That error is because that d object or parameter is undefined or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any parameters with handleClick function on onClick method and you are trying to access some key from the parameter which is undefined so that is why you are getting the error `cannot read property name of undefined`. try passing parameters to that handleClick function:

```
<Button
 variant="contained"
 size="medium"
 color="secondary"
 id={t.acf.job_id}
 name={t.acf.job_name}
 onClick={()=>this.handleClick(param1,param2)}
 >
 Apply
 </Button>
```

Comment: I am using wordpress headless api as backend, the e & d parameters are handles by wordpress. 
When I was using semantic-ui-buttons, the button works.

After I changed the button to material-ui, then the OnClick doesn't work.

Comment: but the error you mentioned is due to the parameters. if you think your button onclick is not working try putting a `console.log('working')` in your handleClick . i dont think there is problem with your button

Comment: Just tried console.log, yes you are right, the error is that the argument is not passed into the parameter ... Don't know why is this happening.

Comment: that is because you are getting parameters as undefined . try `console log('here',d)` in your function you will have more clarity

Comment: add the minimal code to sandbox so that i can help you out more on the issue

Comment: After hours of debugging, I was able to solve the problems. The error is caused by the inconsistency on how I pass the data. Nevertheless, the problem is solved. Thank you for your help!